# What is a non-visual bean?

Tags: java, javabeans, jform-designer

Using JForm Designer I am trying to change the class of a JPanel in the properties window from JPanel to various custom classes, all of which subclass JPanel.

Sometimes it works, sometimes it fails with the message:

panel1: Can not morph non-toplevel component to non-visual bean.

What is a non-visual bean?  Why are some of my subclasses recognized as visual vs. non-visual beans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JForm Designer documentation has been updated.

It now says explicitly that [Visual Beans](http://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/doc/java-beans/?PHPSESSID=samkf5jqc7hiudm2e5pes92jk3) must inherit from java.awt.Component.

I guess that's the all of it.

Answer (score 1):

On this [IBM site](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cmx/v8r3m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cmx.doc/cmbapmst173.htm) it says:

> ## Non-visual beans You can use the non-visual beans to build Java™ and
>
> Web client applications that require a
>   customized user interface. The
>   non-visual beans support the standard
>   bean programming model by providing
>   default constructors, properties,
>   events and a serializable interface.
>   You can use the non-visual beans in
>   builder tools that support
>   introspection.
>
> ## Visual beans The visual beans are customizable, Swing-based, graphical
>
> user interface components. Use the
>   visual beans to build Java
>   applications for Windows®. You can
>   place them within windows and dialogs
>   of Java-based applications. Because
>   the visual beans are built using the
>   non-visual beans (as a data model),
>   you must use them in conjunction with
>   the non-visual beans when building an
>   application.

Comment: I'm looking for a more formal definition.  My class is a customizable, swing-based, graphical UI component.  This sounds like they're saying a visual bean is any JavaBean which derives from a visual Swing component?  But I'm doing this!  There must be something more to it.